# File is corrupt in angular using angular/http module

Tags: node.js, angular, amazon-s3

I am using file saver and angular/http. Upload, delete to s3 bucket is working perfectly, but when I download file it shows corrupt and size of the file is very less (50B)

```
dowlnoad(attachment){
 var filename = attachment.uploadname;
 console.log(filename);
 this.service.downloadFile(filename)
 .subscribe(
    data => saveAs( new Blob([data], { type: 'application/octet-stream' 
    }),filename),
    error=> console.error(error)
)
 return false;
```

}

Comment: does it hit the error message or the success? what is the saveAs function? you probably need `this.saveAs(...`

Comment: Its not hitting the error message, file is downloading but not with the contents. I tried this.saveAs its not working.

Comment: saveAs is imported from file-saver

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
downloadFile(file: string){
var body = {filename:file};

let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/pdf' });
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob });

 this.http.post(`${environment.queryApi}/api/dfile`, body, options).toPromise()
.then(response => this.saveToFileSystem(response,body));;
}

private saveToFileSystem(response,body) {
// const contentDispositionHeader: string = response.headers.get('Content-Disposition');
// const parts: string[] = contentDispositionHeader.split(';');
// const filename = parts[1].split('=')[1];
const blob = new Blob([response._body], { type: 'application/pdf' });
saveAs(blob, body.filename);
return false;
}
```

[response._body] solved the issue